# Imagen de fondo se carga constantemente en Python

Tags: python, pygame

Buen dia, tengo un juego en python al cual le asigne un fondo que quiero que se cambie por otro al llegar a una cantidad de puntos, el problema es que al cambiarse el fondo se carga constantemente y baja el framerate, es porque el if ejecuta constantemente el llamado a la imagen o que no estoy viendo?

```
# Clase para la escena del juego   class Game():
def __init__(self):

    # Cargamos el fondo.
    self.fondo = load_image('Fondo1.png', IMG_DIR)
    self.primera_vez = True 
# Segundo nivel

    if  self.puntos > 1:
        self.fondo = load_image('Fondo2.png', IMG_DIR)
        self.primera_vez = True
```

Le falta una gran cantidad de cosas que no agregue porque son irrelevantes.

Comment: No queda claro para qué usas `self.primera_vez`. Si es para cargarlo sólo una vez, deberías ponerla a `False` al iniciarla, y comprobarla como parte de tu test en `if self.puntos> and not self.primera_vez:`

Comment: si no le pongo el self.primera_vez , cuando llego a X cantidad de puntos queda el primer fondo y se va actualizando al segundo fondo por cada lugar en el que tengo un enemigo o mi personaje o un disparo, como si se fuera pintando encima del primer fondo

Comment: ¿Creaste el ciclo while indeterminado para ejecutar las instrucciones ?  @MrBean es que lo que tratas de hacer es un evento, pero trata de especificar algo mas tu código para poder entender en que podemos ayudarte.

Comment: @Krasnax no, en esta clase (Game) defino cargo y genero todo lo que implica el juego en si, como se hace un evento? nunca necesite hacer eso